# How can I extract the hours, min, sec from the below mentioned format

Tags: iphone

I am making an iphone application in which I want to implement the alarm concept. I am using time picker for time but I am getting the time **2011-08-17 17:00:45 +0530** in this format. Now I want to get the hours, min and seconds different by using range concept or any other concept. How can I do it. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what format would you like to get the hours, minutes and seconds? Or would you just like to extract them from the string you have?

Comment: yes, I want to extract them, so that I can convert them all into seconds for implement the alarm concept.

Comment: Well then you just need to extract substrings of length 2 starting at the right position in the string. What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am not an Objective C expert so I cannot write a solution in this language, but a solution is to extract the substrings at the right positions. You just need to find the right string library functions for Objective C and call them with the appropriate parameters (position, length, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
[format setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[format stringFromDate:yourDate]];
```

And then separate the string into components :

```
NSArray *arr = [str componentSeparatedBy:@" "];  
NSString *strHours = [arr objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *strMinutes = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *strSeconds = [arr objectAtIndex:2];
```

Now convert hours and minutes into seconds :

```
int iHours = [strHours intValue];
if(iHours>12)    //Check for hour more than 12:00 eg 17:00
{
iHours = iHours - 12;
}

int iMinutes = [strMinutes intValue];

int iSeconds = [strSeconds intValue];

intTotalSeconds = (60*60*iHours) + (60*iMinutes) + iSeconds;
```

**iTotalSeconds** are the total seconds you require.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the String to NSDate use:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate* foo = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourDateString];
```

After that you can convert the NSDate to NSDateComponents and get the seconds, minutes etc. from them.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:
(NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:foo];
NSInteger second = [component second];
NSInteger minute = [component minute];
```

Answer (score 0):

Either do a mashup of @Nitish and @cortez's answers (use one DateFormatter to parse the date string, and another to output it in your preferred format), or:

Download and include [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html) in your project.

Then go:

```
#import "RegexKitLite.h"
NSString *timeString = @"2011-08-17 17:00:45 +0530";
NSString *regex = @"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}";
NSString *timeComponent = [timeString stringByMatching:regex capture:1];
```